# How activate GSuite Credits for my Google Cloud Platform startup credits?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I get the Spark plan for Google startups. And here https://cloud.google.com/developers/startups it says that I have G Suite Credits, for up to 10 users.

How/Where can I redeem this feature?

Comment: Congratulations on the Spark Plan. Did you follow the instructions in the email?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I already get the credits to use the Cloud products, but i cant find the GSuit

Answer (score 0):

It means you have a [G-Suite Basic](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6047848?hl=en) plan you should use the SIGN UP wizard from the link I added, this will give you a free 14-day trial from there you can create a [Support Case with G-Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/support/) to make the corresponding changes to your subscription plan.

Or else open a Case with GCP (from GCP Portal "Support > Cases) and let them route it to the proper team since you already have the startup credits you are entitled to receive Support.